# Microsoft Identity Platform

Tags: identity

I have two web apps that need to be SSO enabled. How do I do that in Microsoft Identity platform?. Is there a way to generate two access and refresh token from MSAL and then give access to the API's in Azure AD?

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading through the documentation for [Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/) and then try some of the samples. Here is a link to the [web app samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications) which will sign-in users but also have incremental tutorials to call Microsoft Graph or your own web api.